# if vs. if/else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have this kind of code in a class :

```
if (reload == 0) {
    String mailSuccess = "send success mail";
} else {
    String mailOther = "send other mail";
} 

if (fileError1Exists == true) {
    String mailError1 = "send mail for error 1";
}

if (fileError2Exists == true ) {
    String mailError2 = "send mail for error 2";
}

if (fileError3Exists == true ) {
    String mailError3 = "send mail for error 3";
}
```

And maybe because I am still green with Java, i was wondering if this kind of syntax was clean ? Every time, i saw a "if/ese" expression, it was more like this :

```
if (condition == 0) {
    String mailSuccess = "send success mail";
} else if (fileError1Exists == true) {
    String mailError1 = "send mail for error 1";
} else if (fileError2Exists == true) {
    String mailError2 = "send mail for error 1";
} else if (fileError3Exists == true) {
    String mailError3 = "send mail for error 1";
} else {
    String mailOther = "send other mail";
}
```

Is keeping those if statements one after another like this clean ? Obviously the first sample of code works because it is already in production. But do the 1st sample and the 2nd sample code do the same thing ? Normally, it does, right ? Or am I missing something because of my lack of experience ?

Thanks in advance for your feedback. I couldn't find my awnser on previous posts.

*edit* thank you all for your anwsers. It helped me understand the code, and moreover, it helped me learn something new !

Comment: Just to help you in the future, this has nothing to do with syntax.

Comment: Side note: the two snippets are not equivalent. So no, using the second snippet is not correct if what you need is the behaviour described by the first one. Also, you can avoid all those `== true`, they are not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a matter of requirements given. The first code will send an email for each error found, that means if all 3 errors are found, it will send 3 emails.

Your second code will send one email for the first code found and not for additional ones.

In case you want an email for every single error, take the first code. Otherwise, if you just need one email for the first error that occurs, take the second code.

**EDIT**
To take the suggestion by @Lino into account, you could do something like

```
if (reload == 0) {
    String mailSuccess = "send success mail";
} else {
    String mailOther = "send other mail";
}

StringBuilder mailErrors = new StringBuilder();

if (fileError1Exists) {
    mailErrors.append("error 1 occurred");
}

if (fileError2Exists) {
    mailErrors.append("error 2 occurred");
}

if (fileError3Exists) {
    mailErrors.append("error 3 occurred");
}

String mailErrorText = mailErrors.toString();
```

to track errors and send one email with information about all the errors that occurred.

IMHO tracking every error is best practice.

Comment: The second case could also be written as an `switch` statement

Comment: best would probably be the middle way, track every error but just send one email

Comment: You could probably just do `if (fileError1Exists) {` i.e. remove the `== true`

Comment: @notyou You mean 'you *should* do'.

Answer (score 3):

`if` and  `if-then-else` are conditional statements but have a distinct behavior.

With multiple separated `if` , the JVM may execute `0` to every contained statement in the conditional statements while with a set of `if` used in `if-then-else` the JVM will always execute `0` or `1` contained statement.

As rule of thumb, you will use a set of separated `if` as the processings in the contained conditional statements are **accumulative** and you will use `if-then-else` as the processings in the contained conditional statements are **exclusive**.

The behavior is specified in the JLS.

> **[14.9.1. The if-then Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9.1)**
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, execution continues by making a choice based on the
>   resulting value:
>
> If the value is true, then the contained Statement is executed; ...
>
> If the value is false, no further action is taken and the if-then
>   statement completes normally.

And :

> [**14.9.2. The if-then-else Statement**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9.2)
>
> An if-then-else statement is executed by first evaluating the
>   Expression. If the result is of type Boolean, it is subject to
>   unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, execution continues by making a choice based on the
>   resulting value:
>
> **If the value is true, then the first contained Statement (the one
>   before the else keyword) is executed; the if-then-else statement
>   completes normally if and only if execution of that statement
>   completes normally.**
>
> **If the value is false, then the second contained Statement (the one
>   after the else keyword) is executed;...**

Answer (score 1):

deHaar describes the change in semantics (meaning) of the two versions and offers an improvement.
davidxxx presents the formal JLS definition of `if` statements.
I believe that there's still need for a small example that you can run to clearly see the difference.

```
if (value1) {
  System.out.println("Entry 1");
} else {
  System.out.println("Entry 2");
}

if (value3) {
  System.out.println("Entry 3");
}
```

Depending on the value of `value1` and `value3`, you'll get different output.

- `value1 = true`  and `value3 = true`  prints `Entry1` and `Entry3`
- `value1 = true`  and `value3 = false` prints `Entry1`
- `value1 = false` and `value3 = true`  prints `Entry2` and `Entry3`
- `value1 = false` and `value3 = false` prints `Entry2`

Now the changed program would be as follows:

```
if (value1) {
  System.out.println("Entry 1");
} else if (value3) {
  System.out.println("Entry 3");
} else {
  System.out.println("Entry 2");
}
```

Depending on the value of `value1` and `value3`, you'll get different output.

- `value1 = true`  and `value3 = true`  prints `Entry1`
- `value1 = true`  and `value3 = false` prints `Entry1`
- `value1 = false` and `value3 = true`  prints `Entry3`
- `value1 = false` and `value3 = false` prints `Entry2`

Notice how the output changes when `value3 = true`.